# Why am I getting error: script "dev" exited with code 127

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Coming back to my desk after a cup of coffee, for some reason my terminal started giving the following error:

rex@Rexydoodlesss:/mnt/c/Users/rexh0/AmplifiedChickens/frontend$ bun run dev
$ vite dev
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: vite: command not found
error: script "dev" exited with code 127

Furthermore, when I try to revert to my previous commit, this message appears:

rex@Rexydoodlesss:/mnt/c/Users/rexh0/AmplifiedChickens/frontend$ git reset
fatal: failed to read object c0da248a677249ae54715f6e093e14a2ca927aab: Input/output error

I can't seem to find any related issues; has anyone had experience with this?